# Load Markers in Google Maps according to change in checkbox value in php

Tags: php, google-maps, checkbox

[image: Screen Shot]

hi,
Above is the screenshot of my page. Now currently upon my query below i am displaying the markers in my map.

```
<?
$query=mysql_query("select * from events join event_time         
on(events.event_id=event_time.event_id) where events.isapproved='Y'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$title=$row['title'];
$location=$row['location'];
$sdate=$row['start_date'];
$edate=$row['end_date'];
$stime=$row['start_time'];
$duration=$row['duration'];
$lat=$row['latitude'];
$lon=$row['longitude'];
$address=$row['address'];
$de=$row['description'];
$link=$row['link'];
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$title</b><br/><br/>$sdate ".to."$edate<br/>             
<br/>$address<br/><br/><a>$link</a>');\n");
}
?>
```

below is the add marker fn that currently i am using

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(pt);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: pt,
icon: icon,
map: map
});
```

Now i want the functionality like this, As you can see there is a list of check boxes by the side. I want the functionality like this:
I want to change my marker's display according to my selection of the check box. These check boxes are my category in my database. Can anyone please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('findMarker', customAttribute, variable, separator, function(marker, found) {
                if (found){
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                    bounds.extend(marker.position);
                    marker.map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
                else{
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
```

You have to add a CustomAttribute to your marker, which is the one you will ad to the function, like 'class' for example.

Then, you need to specify (with the checkbox value) which element of this class need to be searched. Finally, you should provide a separator if you have it added. This allow to have multiple 'classes', for example you could have 'foodanddrinks-sports' and that marker would be show in both cases.